# Flutter web integration test freezes unless mouse action

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, flutter-integration-test

I've Flutter tests which are organized in multiple groups and each group have 2-10 tests. All tests runs on `android emulator` without any interruption, but while running on flutter-web, the browser window doesn't move forward after some time of **physical activity** on that browser window. Once I hover mouse and few clicks on window, it continue running tests.

I believe there are some events by native flutter, which freezes current screen unless someone interacts with it. Can anyone help me regarding these events and how to override them so tests keep running even if there is no interaction.